# Trouble saving graduated color style in Spatialite db in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-2, spatialite, color

When I attempt to save a style with graduated colors for a vector layer in a Spatialite db, I receive the following error:

> Error looking for style. The query was logged

I had success saving single symbol and categorized color styles following the workflow [shown here](https://pvanb.wordpress.com/2014/05/15/saving-layer-styles-to-your-spatialite-database/). How can I save my graduated color class in the spatialite db?

QGIS: 2.12.1. Spatialite: 4.1.1

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this have to do with data type involved, graduated color is sometime quite glitchy when it come to real number with a lot of decimals. Look more like a bug than something you can actually resolve.

As a workaround you can try to convert your graduated renderer to a rule based renderer.

Adjust your rendering using graduated color then switch the top left drop-down list to use rule-based renderer.

BUT make sure the generated class limit don't overlap, last time I used this trick some weird <= >= definition was produced when converting graduated to rule.